# Google Oauth not sign-in not working even after app is verified

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

We were setting up google oauth signin for our website. For testing purpose we have added our test email xxx@gmail.com and then submitted add for verification

The problem we are facing is, even though our app is in verified status, our app is not working for all emails. It is working for only for xxx@gmail.com. but other emails its is throwing

> {
> "error": "invalid_grant",
> "error_description": "Bad Request"
> }

upon trying to get access_token https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token using authorization code.
sample auth_code: 4/0AX4XfWh4w99xccU1rPd2qi4hRUkp0Tyya7bOs373nDLbCXjrjvnWxY6uCgiZKRlXeimiFQ
We are struck on this for quite sometime
screen shots

[image: verified status]

Comment: Can you edit your question and include your authorization code.  invalid_grant can be caused by a number of issues.   are you sure your storing tokens for each of your users?

Comment: @DaImTo No. we are not storing tokens.  we are just using authorization_code to get access_token and then user email.

Comment: @DaImTo. I have edited the question to include authorization_code

Comment: Thats not what i meant.  I need to see a  [example] so that i can test the code myself.  The authorization process is a three step process you have only shown step two.   I need to see it all.   As well as the request you are making

Answer (score 0):

The proper request exchanging the authorization code is.

```
HTTP Post https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
code=4/X9lG6uWd8-MMJPElWggHZRzyFKtp.QubAT_P-GEwePvB8fYmgkJzntDnaiAI&client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code
```

If you are getting `invalid_grant` from that, this would sugest that the authorizaotn code has either expired as they are only good for under five minutes. or the authorization code has in fact been used previously in which case it will no longer work.

It could also be that the client id and client secrets you are sending are not the ones that were used to get the authorization code to begin with.

- [Understanding Oauth2 with curl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w)
- [Google 3 Legged OAuth2 Flow](https://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)

## invalid_grant [errors](https://www.daimto.com/google-api-error-list/)

- invalid_grant Your server’s clock is not in sync with NTP. (Solution: check the server time if its incorrect fix it. )
- invalid_grant: Code was already redeemed (you can only use authorizaton code once)
- invalid_grant: Invalid JWT (refrsh token expired)
- Invalid_grant: bad request (client id and client secret don't match refresh token / authorizaotn code)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I will check on my side. One thing puzzle me is like this whole flow works for the test email xxx@gmail.com that we added during test phase. This whole flow for the same email onlyxxx@gmail.com , it works in production as well. Thats weird!! any possible reason?

Comment: Thats why i would really like to see all of your code.  This shouldnt have anything to do with the user who is logged in  its not that kind of error